# Flash development under Ubuntu

Tags: flash, actionscript, flex, ubuntu

It's unfortunate, but I'm taking this course that would require me to work in Flash CS3 (specifically programming), which would make me use windows. I'm very used to development under Ubuntu, and booting into windows would require me to switch a hard drive. I was wondering if:

- I could use the Flex 4.5 SDK to develop (something like a console application), then later hook it in Windows with the GUI I'm required to design? (In other words, is Flex 4.5 SDK compatible with CS3)?
- Is there a good lightweight editor that I can edit actionscript 3 in?

Comment: There's Adobe Air... but they just deprecated it on the Linux desktop. The current version might work for you immediate needs.

Answer (score 1):

Booting into Windows would not necessarily require you to switch a hard drive, you could use a Virtual Windows instance within Ubuntu by using something like VirtualBox.

I use VirtualBox at work for the Microsoft-dependent programs I need to run.  Everything else can run happily in Ubuntu.

Comment: Lol. My windows installation is on a different harddrive. After years of pain of development under windows due to not been able to make ATI PowerXpress work with the Linux kernel and Xorg, I'm done. Here I am trying to be independent of IDEs, and use an editor, console, and debugger.

Comment: Heh. But for something proprietary like Flash, you're really better off using the official thing.  Is there a reason why a Windows VM within your Ubuntu system wouldn't work?

Comment: It would.. I don't like it. I'm doing that now.... Install XP xD